# How to show $(p\land q) \to r$ is logically equivalent to $p \to (q\to r)$?

Tags: logic

I need to show the following statement is logically equivalent:

> Show $(p \land q ) \to r$ is logical equivalent to $p\to (q \to r)$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Maths.SE! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Comment: "Need to show" using what? Truth-tables? A natural deduction proof?? A proof in another formal deductive system???

Comment: Intuitively, it's obvious. If $p$ and $q$ imply $r$, then if we know $p$ is true, there only remains to verify $q$ in order to conclude $r$.

Answer (score 4):

We use the following identity repeatedly: $$a \rightarrow b \equiv \lnot a \lor b\tag{1}$$
and we use one of DeMorgan's Rules once: $$\lnot(a \land b) \equiv \lnot a \lor \lnot b\tag{2}$$

---

$$\begin{align} (p \land q ) \to r & \equiv \lnot(p \land q) \lor r\tag{by (1)} \\ \\
& \equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \lor r \tag{by (2)}\\ \\ 
& \equiv \lnot p \lor( \lnot q \lor r) \tag{associativity of $\lor$} \\ \\
& \equiv \lnot p \lor (q \rightarrow r)\tag{by (1)}\\ \\
& \equiv p \rightarrow(q\rightarrow r) \tag{by (1)} 
\end{align}$$

Comment: How does this not have any votes - rectified! +1

Comment: Look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52990/bridging-any-gaps-between-ap-calculus-and-college-univ-level-calculus-ii) it is written that it is protected by me; I do not remember that I did this and I do not even know how to do LOL

Comment: Oh, that's funny!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: 
\begin{align*}
p \implies (q \implies r) &\equiv p \implies (r \vee \neg q) \\
&\equiv (r \vee \neg q) \vee \neg p \\
&\equiv r \vee (\neg p \vee \neg q) \\
&\equiv r \vee \neg (p \wedge q)
\end{align*}

where we have used the definition of implication and De Morgan's Laws.

Answer (score 2):

$(p\land q)\to r\equiv \lnot(p\land q)\lor r \equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r$

$p\to (q\to r)\equiv p\to (\lnot q \lor r)\equiv \lnot p\lor (\lnot q \lor r)\equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r$

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, use truth table.

Syntactically, for one direction, assume $(P\wedge Q)\rightarrow R$ and $P$ and $Q$, then $P\wedge Q$. Then use Modus Ponens to get $R$ and apply Deduction Theorem twice to get $P\rightarrow(Q\rightarrow R)$. Conversely, assume $P\rightarrow(Q\rightarrow R)$ and $P\wedge Q$, then $P$ and $Q$. Then apply Modus Ponens twice to get $R$ and apply Deduction Theorem to get $(P\wedge Q)\rightarrow R$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a truth table and compare both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Big Hint that leads Immediately to the Answer: Figure out what $p$, $q$, and $r$ need to be in order for each expression to be false.